# Excel - VBA - Chart how to use array for Y axis

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, charts, axis

I am still learning about coding and I have encountered a new problem. 
To sum it up, I have four columns : 
the first one with dates, the second one with categories, the third one with names and the fourth one with specificities.

I have to write a program so that data would **automatically** sort itself in a scatter chart so that :
- the y axis is sorted by categories (which I am having trouble with as it is text, and all my points are then ordered on the horizontal axis)
- each point is labeled as such : with the name above it and the specificities below
- the dates are on the x-axis (and for doing that, the only way I found was to add one by one the data (line by line), instead of selecting all of my columns, which I recorded in the macro. I can keep that part but I tried to find a way and thought I would if you may have insight on that also)

My main issue is to find a way to tell my macro to **sort the y-axis by categories**.

[image: This is what the data looks like (except there are about 200 lines)]

This is what the data looks like (except there are about 200 lines)

My goal is to have a graph that would put points at the intersection of their categories and dates. (Then the macro would have to put the "Names" Data above each corresponding point and the "Characteristcis" Data under them.) like below :
[image: What the chart should look like]

Would you mind please helping me with how to do that ?

Thank you a lot for your help (and sorry again  if there were any English mistakes)

Comment: A scatter chart has axes that are both numeric. If you want to plot categoric data on one axis then it isn't a scatter chart - although maybe you need to create some dummy numeric data so you can fake what you want it to look like using a scatter chart in Excel. (I assume this is Excel? If so you should tag it as such.) Can you show us an example of the data and what you want the chart to look like?

Comment: Yes it is Excel, sorry forgot to add it.
I will try to put an image of what the data and objective look like

Comment: Is there a fixed list of possible categories or could they be completely different from one data set to the next? Will there ever be two data points with the same date and category and if so what do you want that to look like?

Comment: There is no fixed list of possible categories. Depending on the subject addressed, it could be completely different. There could be two data points with the same date and category, in which case I thought I would just have one point (or they could overlap, it doesn't matter) but the names and characteritics would have to be differentiated and readable. 
So far I've written a macro that adds one by one the series to the chart and replaced the categories with numbers (each category has one) so that I can try to have a visual but I don't know whether it's a good idea or where to go from there

Comment: Adding a dummy column of numbers corresponding to the categories will work, at least it will allow you to use an Excel scatter chart. I'm not sure how you will get the chart to display all the text you want though. This free add-in might help, if you can open it to inspect its VBA code: http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm

Comment: All right, thank you very much, I will try to find a way. Unfortunately my company is very strict on confidentiality and I still haven't been able to download the labeler. Thks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution to my question.
There are actually several ways to get there.

If you only have two categories, then you can select the y-axis and modify it like this :
you select "number" and type in the type box something like this in any number format

[=1] "Category 1";[=2] "Category 2"

Then add it to the personalized format and select it. This will display the two catgeories instead of the numbers.

However if you have more than two categories, it gets a bit trickier.
As I had first tried, you must create a dummy column full of numbers that you'll then replace. The rest is better explained there : http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/Y_CategoryAxis.html

Hope it helps !